# Can I use a CIviCRM Webform URL in place of the required action.unsubscribeUrl?

Tags: civimail, drupal, webform-civicrm, tokens

I created a nice un/subscrube form using the excellent CiviCRM Webform module for Drupal. Now I would like to send mailings with CiviMail and include a link to my webform as the unsubscribe option.

However, CiviMail refuses to send my mailing unless I include the token `action.unsubscribeUrl` or `action.optOutUrl` in the content of my mailing.

What is the proper way to set my webform URL *as* my `action.unsubscribeUrl`?

Background discussion [here](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=19728.0). I realize there is a change that will be committed soon that will allow a token to exempt a mailing from this requirement. https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16062

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can already disable the setting so the tokens aren't mandatory, then use add your url to the webform (with the contact id and token checksum so they are "logged")

It's under Administer>civimail>civimail component setting http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/mailing?reset=1

Comment: Thank you, I missed that setting when I was looking in there earlier today. I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there isn't an "easy" way to create a token for unsubscribe webforms. As X said you can turn off the unsubscribe requirement but this is a blunt instrument and requires you to still manually construct the checksum link to the webform each time.

If you're up for a little coding exercise, how about submitting a Pull-Request to the Webform-CiviCRM project implementing hook_civicrm_tokens?

Comment: What I do is put it (once) in the footer and voila, link all the time. But C's idea would be even easier indeed.